# Resources are not available in C++ Multi-threading

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to understand why when I try to use threading in writing to a file. It stops writing to this file after sometime. I understand threading but not too much deep.
Here is the sample code I am using:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
# include <stdio.h>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>
// http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/cpptut.php
using namespace std;

float counter = 0;

void *call_from_thread(void *) {
        FILE *f = fopen64("results_text.txt", "a");
        if (f == NULL)
            {
                printf("Error opening file!\n");
                exit(1);
            }    

        fprintf(f, " this is some text to be written in the file to see the max size of writting using threads \n");

        fclose(f);    
        printf("|I am in the thread \n" );    
        usleep(50);    
        return NULL;
}


int main() {    
    while (true) {    
        std::thread t([] {call_from_thread(NULL);});

        counter++;
        // To let the main thread continue running and detach from the last created thread, the thread must have finished execution before recalling it once again.
        // if the thread sleeps more than the main thread, then after some time the program will run out of resources and the program crash
        // to test this case: try to put 5000 in the usleep inside the thread
        t.detach();
        // Will make the main thread wait for the thread till it finishes
        //t.join();

        printf("|I am alive %f \n", counter);    
        usleep(100);
    }

return 0;
}
```

I am using "detach" function to conserve the resources on my computer, but still after running some while I get the following error:

```
 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `detach` doesn't conserve any resources. You are creating an unbounded number of threads and the program (predictably) dies after exceeding an OS threshold for the number of threads. What did you expect would happen instead?

Comment: I want to run a test in the main thread and capture the results using another thread and save the results in the file. I know that "detach" let the parent thread not wait for the threadid to finish. Basically, I want to call the same thread several times to perform the same task without creating another resource of a thread.

Comment: @halim So you want a thread pool http://progsch.net/wordpress/?p=81

Comment: Then create a fixed number of threads, putting their handles in a `vector`. Have the threads obtain their tasks from a thread-safe queue and have the main threads fill up the queue. Any decent thread pool library will let you do this in a couple lines of code.

Comment: I found this implementation for the thread polling, [Code on github](https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool) , it is complementary to what @Stargateur hinted to.